# Treat new column in multicol as a new page

Tags: multicol, vspace

So I'm using multicol to have two columns, and I'm writing test questions in the columns, with spaces between them. I want LATEX to ignore the spacing before the question if it's at the start of a column.

I'm generating my test with code, so I don't know how long the questions are going to be, that's why I need it done automatically.

I'd appreciate any suggestions/advice since I'm not very experienced with LATEX. Any other feedback about my document not regarding my question is greatly appreciated too.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{enumitem, tikz, pgffor, amsmath, amssymb, multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{255, 91, 91}

\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\textbf{\arabic{question}}}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\thequestion.)}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@fullhead}
{\hrule}{{\color{myred}\hrule height 3pt}}{}{ERROR}
\patchcmd{\@fullfoot}
{\hrule}{{\color{myred}\hrule height 3pt}}{}{ERROR}
\patchcmd{\run@fullhead}
{\hrule}{{\color{myred}\hrule height 3pt}}{}{ERROR}
\patchcmd{\run@fullfoot}
{\hrule}{{\color{myred}\hrule height 3pt}}{}{ERROR}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\lhead{\LARGE Number Place and Value Test 7\\\large\today\\John Smith}
\extraheadheight{1in}
\headrule
\extrawidth{0.5in}

\extrafootheight{0.9in}
\footrule
\lfoot{\textbf{Instructions}\\
1. Complete the test and check your answers.\\
2. Scan the QR Code and input your score.}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
\large
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{questions}
\question Of the following numbers, which is the largest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $5447738$
\choice $4437381$
\choice $8305907$
\choice $9339827$
\choice $1442711$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the smallest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $8092823$
\choice $9367490$
\choice $1964529$
\choice $3149875$
\choice $5745315$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the largest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $3980605$
\choice $9702282$
\choice $6237650$
\choice $3644015$
\choice $1358666$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the smallest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $8664126$
\choice $6070860$
\choice $9420803$
\choice $5754384$
\choice $6398766$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the smallest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $6277328$
\choice $8809736$
\choice $5887283$
\choice $5716170$
\choice $8087313$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the largest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $3547326$
\choice $8074229$
\choice $1739227$
\choice $7196233$
\choice $7989985$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the largest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $8106934$
\choice $5161059$
\choice $1049957$
\choice $7216725$
\choice $2280085$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the largest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $8706155$
\choice $6938591$
\choice $9936690$
\choice $7389161$
\choice $2335232$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the largest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $1740135$
\choice $6280320$
\choice $3640218$
\choice $9420925$
\choice $5535432$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the smallest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $5226418$
\choice $7674107$
\choice $2199521$
\choice $5343271$
\choice $4811082$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the smallest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $5810212$
\choice $1121923$
\choice $3706036$
\choice $1049400$
\choice $2767112$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the smallest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $7831316$
\choice $1884191$
\choice $7804065$
\choice $2706287$
\choice $8962263$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the smallest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $1239644$
\choice $8946088$
\choice $1128256$
\choice $5005934$
\choice $1278918$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the smallest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $2223682$
\choice $1485906$
\choice $4219615$
\choice $3168707$
\choice $7829260$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the largest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $5496415$
\choice $6843932$
\choice $9690317$
\choice $2898830$
\choice $1994056$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the smallest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $8909168$
\choice $7167479$
\choice $1832324$
\choice $4744659$
\choice $9809512$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the smallest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $9770245$
\choice $6594567$
\choice $9425455$
\choice $9831149$
\choice $2715294$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the smallest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $3421745$
\choice $8146859$
\choice $6934543$
\choice $9856352$
\choice $6768593$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the smallest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $6937444$
\choice $8416242$
\choice $8364624$
\choice $2111396$
\choice $5888083$
\end{oneparchoices}
\item[\vspace{\fill}]
\question Of the following numbers, which is the largest?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice $9358811$
\choice $9185411$
\choice $2653630$
\choice $3354152$
\choice $6455801$
\end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image: The space before question 1 is good, but not for question 5]

[image: Both question 9 and 13 have too much space before them.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `\item[\vspace{\fill}]` with `\vspace{\fill}` will make the problem go away.

[image: a]

[image: b]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I don't know why I had `\item` there, it must have solved a problem that no longer exists.